# Need help with Sigma-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I am confused on how to determine a Sigma-algebra.

The following partitions of a set are given:
$$
A1 = \{1,3\} $$ $$
A2 = \{2,4,6,8\} $$  $$
A3 = \{5,7,9\}$$
And Omega is $$
\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}
$$

I know that at least Omega and the empty set has to be part of the Sigma-algebra as well as the single partitions and their complements:
$$
\sigma(A1,A2,A3) = \{\emptyset,\Omega,\{1,3\},\{2,4,5,6,7,8,9\},\{2,4,6,8\},\{1,3,5,7,9\},\{5,7,9\},\{1,2,3,4,6,8\}\}
$$

Additionally, there has to be the union of the elements inside and this is the point I am not sure about. Are the following elements part of the Sigma-algebra as well?
$$ A1 \cup A2 = \{1,2,3,4,6,8\}$$
$$ A2 \cup A3 = \{2,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$$
$$ A1 \cup A3 = \{1,3,5,7,9\} $$
$$ A1 \cup A2 \cup A3 = \Omega $$

I think I can ignore all of them since they are already in my Sigma-algebra.

Is my Sigma-algebra fullfinished and where my thoughts about creating the algebra correct? I know that there have to be 2^n elements inside the algebra and due to the fact of there are 8 elements this might be a correct solution.

**Another question:**

In case a union (e.g. A1 U A2) would not have been in the algebra. Do I just have to add A1 U A2 to the algebra or also its complement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right on target. The ($\sigma$-)algebra on $\Omega$ generated by the partition $\{A_1,A_2,A_3\}$ is precisely $$\{\emptyset,A_1,A_2,A_3,A_1\cup A_2,A_1\cup A_3,A_2\cup A_3,\Omega\}.$$ More generally, if you're given a partition of any set $\Omega$ into $n$ subsets, the ($\sigma$-)algebra on $\Omega$ generated by that partition will consist of $2^n$ subsets, consisting of all finite unions of the partition elements (including the empty union).

When you aren't dealing with partitions, it is less simple. At that point, you'll need to worry about complements. Roughly speaking, take all the countable unions, take all the complements, and repeat until you're done.

Comment: Thanks!
Don't I have to unite all the partitions as well?
$$ A1 \cup A2 \cup A3 $$
In my script there's something like
$$ \sigma(A1,...An) = \{A1^{\epsilon1} \cup A2^{\epsilon2} \cup ... \cup An^{\epsilon_n} : \epsilon_i \in \{0,1\}, i=1,...,n\} $$
and this has confused me. I thought I have to unite all elements as well.

Comment: Yes, but $A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3=\Omega,$ so that's in there. As for the other thing, I suspect it is intended that $A^0=\emptyset$ and $A^1=A$, so (for example) $A_1\cup A_2=A_1^1\cup A_2^1\cup A_3^0$ has the desired form, as does $\emptyset=A_1^0\cup A_2^0\cup A_3^0,$ as does $\Omega=A_1^1\cup A_2^1\cup A_3^1.$

Comment: Ah okay, I think I got it!
If I take a look at the superiored numbers, I think I just have to unite each combination of them
000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111 which are 2^3 possibilities, right? And 000 is the empty set an 111 the omega. Thats why there are always 2^n possibilities. I got it!

the only question left is when I have to determine the complements. In this case I didn't really need them.
Or can I say that e.g. 001 is the complement of 110 and e.g. 101 the complement of 010? I didn't calculated it but I think that is correct?

Comment: Bingo! That's exactly right.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I still have a last but short question to the topic. In case there are doubled or empty partitions, can I just ignore them?

Comment: Your terminology is a bit shaky. A *partition* of a set $\Omega$ is a collection $\mathscr P$ of pairwise disjoint, non-empty subsets of $\Omega,$ such that $\Omega=\bigcup\mathscr P.$ The empty set should never be a member of a partition, then, nor should any elements of $\Omega$ lie in more than one partition element. Does that clear it up for you?

Comment: Therefore, the findings from this study can be generalized to a of a partition $(A_i)i \in I$.

Comment: @Zbigniew: That's true.

Comment: I apologise for this blunder. Another  message is posted.

Comment: "The empty set should never be a member of a partition"
Well, In my study homework there is an excercise:

How changes the amount of element of a Sigma-Algebra if exactly k sets $$ A_{i_1},..A_{i_k}, {i_j} \in \{1,...,n\}, j=1,...,k  $$ are empty?
That was the intention of the question. Sorry if it was a bit shaky. If k sets are empty I thought there can be also doubled sets since k empty sets are doubled, too.

Comment: @Drudge: Ah! I see. That is a rare convention, but some texts just require the partition elements to be pairwise-disjoint. In that case, then, only $n-k$ of the sets would make any difference in the unions (so, yes, we can ignore the empty sets), and so there would be $2^{n-k}$ sets in the ($\sigma$-)algebra, instead. Now, if (as I suspect) your book requires that the elements of a partition are still pairwise disjoint, then **only** empty sets can be "doubled" in this way. Can you see why?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see why only emty sets can be doubled.  I would guess that two empty sets are still pairwise-disjoint by definition while two "filled" sets aren't disjoint since they own both the same element(s).
But when re-reading the exercise the following sentence is given:"Let A1,A2,...,An be non-empty and disjoint subsets of a basic set."
So I think the answer to the excercise is that it's not possible because this convention was ignored.
By the way, is there a difference between disjoint and pairwise-disjoint in this case?

Comment: @Drudge: I'd bet that for the first part of the exercise, you're supposed to assume that the $A_i$ are all non-empty, while for the second part, you were supposed to allow exactly $k$ of them to be empty, so the answer changes from $2^n$ to $2^{n-k}$. In this case, I suspect that your book means "pairwise-disjoint" when it says "disjoint." Typically, we say that *two sets* are "disjoint" if they have no common elements; we say that *a collection of sets* is "pairwise disjoint" if for every pair of sets in the collection, the pair is disjoint. Your book is probably just abbreviating things.

Comment: @Drudge: Also, you're exactly right about why we can't double the non-empty sets. The empty set is the only set that is disjoint from itself.

Comment: Thank you a lot Cameron Buie. Stylistically, the convention was before all those excercises on my sheet of paper. The excercises where indented afterwards. I think I'll write both answers and refer to the convention, whether it has to be true or not. That's the most safe way in my eyes to archieve my points. Thank you again, you've been a really big help to me!

Comment: @Drudge: You are very welcome. I'm glad you are persistent and observant. Not everyone is either of those things, which makes them very frustrating to interact with.